# VeriFLY: positive PCR for Canada

Tags: canada, covid-19, british-airways

Trying to upload a positive test (proof of recovery certificate) after 14 days which is an approved method of entry into CANADA. The VeriFLY app will not allow this. What can I do?

Comment: My understanding (flying from Germany to the UK with BA) is that VeriFly is optional - you can still check-in at the airport and show your documents to one of the BA staff.

Comment: seriously? a company took an abbreviation that was already in use (PCR Polymerase chain reaction test for whether you currently have covid or not), where positive means BAD and you can't fly, and decided to use it for a different covid thing, where positive means you can fly? How ridiculous is that??

Comment: @KateGregory, I believe that Hannon wants/needs to travel using the exemption for those who have recovered - i.e. he had COIVID a few weeks/months in the part. Thus he needs to upload a positive test result (showing he *had* COIVD) dating back to that time.

Comment: I understand that @neiltarrant. I was commenting on choosing to name something "PCR (proof of recovery certificate)" when "(PCR Polymerase chain reaction)" is already in widespread use in the same context with the opposite meaning. But now I see that in fact the abbreviation is not the same. Editing question.

Comment: I checked in 2 weeks ago with BA from DXB traveling to Toronto and although I had my VeriFLY approved, the checkin staff did not ask for it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over.